# The following classes couldn't be instantiated

Tags: java, android, android-studio

On my homeactivity.xml it says:
The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)

Here is my code

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#ff4747"
        app:popupTheme="@style/PopupOverlay" />


<include layout="@layout/content_home" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
    android:background="#001f9c" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

I don't know why this happened. Can someone please help?

Comment: it's seems to be that you mising some dependencies in `build.gradle`

Comment: I think you have not added android support design library in your gradle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as commented you have to include the `dependencies` for design which is like this, this will be added under the `dependencies` block of the `app` module of the `build.gradle`

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
```

it should be something like this ..

[image]

if the `design` `dependencies` is not included in the `build.gradle` and  you try to use mentioned `classes` in your question you will not be able to render those `classes` and the error you get in layout would be something like this

[image]

Comment: @PankajNimgade my Android Studio 1.5.1 adds that line automatically. Even then, I have a whole bunch of rendering problems, which is super frustrating since I believe I have all the requisite libraries including support. Despite so many Q&A on SO about rendering issues, I had to add [a question of my own](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35902013/update-messed-up-android-studio-environment) in despair.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded to Android Studio 2.0. That solve the problem for me. I can see the render now. My only error message at this point is: "