# Android Studio 1.5.1 rendering problems

Tags: android, android-studio, android-theme

I'm new to android studio and I have a new version installed (version 1.5.1).
For some reason I keep getting an error message (every time I use an app theme) saying that there were rendering problems: styles missing.
I looked online for solutions, but most of them are outdated or just do not work.

[image: An image of the error]

Thanks for any help.

Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.easycodingplus.myapplication">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Build gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.easycodingplus.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio rendering problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195807/android-studio-rendering-problems)

Comment: I have seen this page, but it is **outdated** and wouldn't work in my version of android studio (1.5.1)

Comment: This post is more recent. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30879510/could-not-initialize-class-android-support-design-widget-coordinatorlayout/30927887#30927887

Comment: @Yaron Give a try with an AppCompat theme in the preview window.

Comment: I still get an error.

Comment: put your Build.Gradle also please.

Comment: here is the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34702858/the-following-classes-couldnt-be-instantiated/34703354#34703354

Answer (score 4):

just change your `style.xml` file like this

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

and then, go to

> File > Project Structure > app >

and set (both should be same with latest version )

`source compatibility : 1.7`

`Target compatibility : 1.7`

Comment: I just changed the `Target` and `Source` compatibility from blank to 1.7 and then the screen loaded fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure you have the lateset AppCompat library listed as a dependency in your build.gradle file:

com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0

Can you post which style the error is referring to? You may need to add a style to your res > values > styles folder. Something in your code is probably referencing a style that does not exists in that folder.

Comment: Thank you, but this didn't help.
I have  "compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'" and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

you have to include the `dependencies` for design which is like this, this will be added under the `dependencies` block of the `app` module of the `build.gradle`

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
```

it should be something like this ..

you need this support library as `CoordinatorLayout`, `AppBarLayout` and `FloatingActionButton` part of it

[image]

make a style in the style file

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

and reference that in your AndroidManifest file

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">// like this
```

Comment: I already have a line of code that looks like this:
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'

Comment: @Yaron, did you sync Project with gradle files?

Comment: I had issue with this kind so I changes the style from this <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light"> to this <style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light"> which worked for me

Comment: I did, but it didn't help, as I said before I looked online and tried as many solutions as possible but none of them worked.

Comment: @Yaron, there is something wrong with your theme, try using AppCompat

Answer (score 0):

try this way:

keep your internet connection

go to "file" in android studio toolbar click on "invalidate caches/Restart" and choose "invalidate and restart"

Comment: I don't have this option.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem so what I did...go to `sdk` manager -->tick android 5.1.1 api level 22 and installed it....
[image: tick android 5.1.1 api level 22 and installed it..]
then go to Preview window and select other version

[image: then go to Preview window and select other version]

Answer (score 0):

3 options

**1.Select low-level API version**

[image: I have 23 but you can go for 19 or 21]

**2.Add Base on styles.xml**

[image: select theme from AppTheme or dealer here]

**3.Install previous SDK (if you want)**

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same problem and these steps helped me solve it:
1. File > Other settings > Default Settings > Appearances & Behaviour > File encoding.
2. Change project encoding to windows-1252. Then:
3. File > Invalidate Chaches/Restart.
              OR WORST CASE
Change the theme to Material light or something else, one of them should work.
I hope this helps.