# Update messed up Android Studio environment

Tags: android, android-studio

After updating Android Studio and everything related via the SDK Manager, I can no longer create the simplest of apps containing a single Blank Activity, because of all these rendering problems. Choosing an Empty Activity still seems manageable though.

Coming back to my Blank Activity issue, this is a summary of my environment:

```
Android Studio 1.5.1
Android SDK Tools 24.4.1
Android SDK Platform Tools 23.1
Android SDK Build Tools 23.0.2
Android Support Library 23.2
```

I see a ton of rendering problem error messages on both activity_main.xml and content_main.xml. I changed the theme to Holo Light, I downgraded the API level in the IDE to 19, but to no avail. I have both activity_main.xml and content_main.xml displaying grayed out CoordinatorLayout. So I cannot drag any components onto the layout in the IDE. What am I missing?!

Edit 3/10/2016: Adding detail on setup and the error messages...

This is my app's build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.udemycourse.notes"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
}
```

> ```
> Missing styles. Is the correct theme chosen for this layout?
> Note: One or more layouts are missing the layout_width or layout_height attributes. These are required in most layouts.
> The following classes could not be instantiated:
> android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
> android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
> android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
> ```
>
> Exception displayed in the rendering window:
>       java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library.  at
>   android.support.design.widget.ThemeUtils.checkAppCompatTheme(ThemeUtils.java:34)
>     at
>   android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout.(AppBarLayout.java:145)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:458)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:170)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:103)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:168)
>     at
>   android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:247)
>     at
>   android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:171)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:835)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:811)    at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)  at
>   com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:223)
>     at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:426)
>     at
>   com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:350)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:510)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:498)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:888)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:498)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.access$600(RenderTask.java:72)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:610)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:607)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.runRenderAction(RenderService.java:362)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:607)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:629)
>     at
>   com.intellij.android.designer.designSurface.AndroidDesignerEditorPanel$6.run(AndroidDesignerEditorPanel.java:480)
>     at
>   com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
>     at
>   com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
>     at
>   com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
>     at
>   com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
>     at
>   com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
>     at
>   com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
>     at
>   com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
>     at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:351)    at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: well you are facing one of generic issues which can be avoided by using a theme which comes from AppCompact. which would be this Theme.AppCompat, either use it or some sub classed theme from it. and that should work.

Comment: @PankajNimgade When I changed to AppCompat, one class still could not be instantiated: `android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton`. This is in `activity_main.xml`. In content_main.xml`. there is an exception stack that also mentions FloatingActionButton, but the design view does not explicitly mention that the class cannot be instantiated. I even tried the Invalidate Cache / Restart option since a number of other Q&As talk about that as a possible resolution... but to no avail. :-(

Comment: When you view the layout is there anything that pops up that says clear cache?

Comment: @WebUser, I guess i did locate the issue, for some reason you might be this because of the change in the style of the theme try to revert the default theme generated by the android studio it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Things you should take care of while using `App Compact` along with `Toolbar` that you are using a decedent of `Theme.AppCompat` Theme like this Theme **AppTheme**. As you are getting the current error.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

In your `AndroidManifest.xml` file make sure your application element has this attribute `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"`. you may want to remove theme attribute from individual Activities.

> Eg

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

if you are still facing some configuration issues with the project, kindly check this [repository](https://github.com/pankajnimgade/Realm-Example), it's a dummy code but you can compare your project with it. If you are still facing issue let me know.

You might want to replace `build.gradle` dependencies with these

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'

File => Project Structure =>
```

now click on the `app` in given module and then on dependencies.

[image]